# Apache Netbeans printing a symbol directly after a Swedish letter

Tags: java, output

This is my code:

```
package uppgift2_3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Uppgift2_3 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Substantiv: ");
        String substantiv = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Pluraländelse: ");
        String pluraländelse = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("En " +substantiv+ ", flera " +substantiv+pluraländelse);
    }
}
```

and this what I see in the output:

```
run:
Substantiv: häst
Pluraländelse: ar
En hÃ¤st, flera hÃ¤star
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

The symbol '¤' should not be there, and is only appearing directly after the swedish letters ä, å and ö.

I am using the encoding 'ISO-8859-1'which I believe is the correct one as my teacher has instructed us to use this. I of course have tried restarting netbeans. This happens in every project that I start and I don't think the issue is with my code. I'd appreciate any help with solving this :)

Comment: How are you using ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Comment: In the properties of the project, I find encoding and chose that ISO, as my teacher has instructed.

Comment: That's probably the result of printing Utf-8 with Latin encoding

Comment: `'\xC3\xA4'` is  ä in utf-8 and in Latin1                            it's Ã¤